# How to get the specific content from the log file described bellow?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list

I Have a log file which is generated by nmap, which is something like this:

```
Nmap scan report for gateway (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0060s latency).
MAC Address: 10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65 (D-Link International)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.2
Host is up (0.055s latency).
MAC Address: 7C:78:7E:E8:1C:2A (Samsung Electronics)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.3
Host is up (0.059s latency).
MAC Address: 54:60:09:83:6E:B6 (Google)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.200
Host is up (-0.093s latency).
MAC Address: 5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8 (Hewlett Packard)
Nmap scan report for manoj-notebook (10.0.0.4)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 16.84 seconds
```

It keeps on changing as the new devices connect to the network or existing device disconnects from the network. I want to fetch the ip address example: `10.0.0.1`, mac address example: `10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65` and the device name example: `D-Link International` in a single list something like:

```
result = [['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.200', '10.0.0.4'], ['10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '7C:78:7E:E8:1C:2A', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8'], ['D-Link International', 'Samsung Electronics', 'Google', 'Hewlett Packard']]
```

I tried the following regular expression to match IP address, MAC Address and Device name:

```
ipPattern = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', temp)
macPattern = re.findall(r'(?:.*?s: ){2}(.*)(?= \))', temp)
devicePattern = re.findall(r'(?:.*?\(){2}(.*)(?=\))', temp)
```

I'm able to match the IP Address but unable to match mac address and device name. How to match the same and store it in a single list? Thank you.

Also if I could get a pattern to fetch latency from the log file example: `0.0060s` it would be a cherry on top. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expressions:

- *ipPattern* : `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b`
- *macPattern* : `(?:[0-9A-F]{2}:){2,}[0-9A-F]{2}\b`

  - `(?:[0-9A-F]{2}:)+` Non capturing group for sequence of pairs of alphanumerical values followed by `:`.
  - `[0-9A-F]+\b` Final pair of alphanumerical value, followed by word boundary.
- *devicePattern* : `(?<=\()[^)0-9.]*(?=\))`

  - `(?<=\()` Negative lookbehind for bracket `)`.
  - `[^)0-9.]*` Negated character set, matches anything that is not a `)` or `.` or digits.
  - `(?=\))` Positive lookahead for `)`.
- *latency* : `-?\d+\.\d+s(?=\slatency)`

  - `-?\d+\.\d+s` Match `-` optionally, digits, full stop, more digits and `s`.
  - `(?=\slatency)` Positive lookahead, assert that what follows whitespace and `latency`.

---

Python snippet:

```
import re
import itertools


temp = """
b'\nStarting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-03 19:44 IST\nNmap scan report for gateway (10.0.0.1)\nHost is up (0.0070s latency).\nMAC Address: 10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65 (D-Link International)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.3\nHost is up (0.11s latency).\nMAC Address: 54:60:09:83:6E:B6 (Google)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.5\nHost is up (0.11s latency).\nMAC Address: 7C:78:7E:A4:73:8C (Samsung Electronics)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.200\nHost is up (0.027s latency).\nMAC Address: 5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8
"""

ipPattern = re.findall(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', temp)
macPattern= re.findall(r'(?:[0-9A-F]{2}:){2,}[0-9A-F]{2}\b',temp)
devicePattern = re.findall(r'(?<=\()[^)0-9.]*(?=\))',temp)
latency = re.findall(r'-?\d+\.\d+s(?=\slatency)',temp)

print(ipPattern)
print(macPattern)
print(devicePattern)
print(latency)
```

Prints:

```
['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5', '10.0.0.200']
['10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '7C:78:7E:A4:73:8C', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8']
['D-Link International', 'Google', 'Samsung Electronics']
['0.0070s', '0.11s', '0.11s', '0.027s']
```

For joining in a single list use:

```
mylist = itertools.chain([ipPattern], [macPattern], [devicePattern], [latency])
print(list(mylist))
```

Prints:

```
[['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5', '10.0.0.200'], ['10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '7C:78:7E:A4:73:8C', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8'], ['D-Link International', 'Google', 'Samsung Electronics'], ['0.0070s', '0.11s', '0.11s', '0.027s']]
```

Comment: `[['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5', '10.0.0.200', '10.0.0.4']]
[['19:28', '10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '7C:78:7E:A4:73:8C', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8']]
[[]]` I'm getting output in this manner , the device pattern is failing is it?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, just copy and paste my code and try?

Comment: `['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.200', '10.0.0.4']
['19:40', '10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8']
[]
['0.0066s', '0.042s', '0.0039s']
[['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.200', '10.0.0.4'], ['19:40', '10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65', '54:60:09:83:6E:B6', '5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8'], [], ['0.0066s', '0.042s', '0.0039s']]` I tried copy pasting your code and still its failing :(

Comment: `b'\nStarting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-03 19:44 IST\nNmap scan report for gateway (10.0.0.1)\nHost is up (0.0070s latency).\nMAC Address: 10:BE:F5:FC:9C:65 (D-Link International)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.3\nHost is up (0.11s latency).\nMAC Address: 54:60:09:83:6E:B6 (Google)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.5\nHost is up (0.11s latency).\nMAC Address: 7C:78:7E:A4:73:8C (Samsung Electronics)\nNmap scan report for 10.0.0.200\nHost is up (0.027s latency).\nMAC Address: 5C:B9:01:02:5F:D8` to be more precise this is the temp variable

Comment: Right, that makes a difference.. Please modify your open post with that text and see updated answer.